# An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am making a call to asynchronous operation with the following line of code:

```
Task.Run(() => { _emailService.SendEmail(email); }).Wait();


public async Task<bool> SendEmail(EmailTemplate email)
{
    try
    {
        using (Client)
        {
            await Client.SendMailAsync(email.Message);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString(), "Error occurred while sending an Email.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the code ran the first time, it worked without issues and I received my email, however when I run it every other time since I get the following 2 errors:

> 2016-02-04 15:50:05.3039 [11] FATAL ExceptionHandling.Models.EmailService+d__0.MoveNext - System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient'.
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(MailMessage message, Object userToken)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailAsync(MailMessage message)
>      at ExceptionHandling.Models.EmailService.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> 2016-02-04 16:33:09.9768 [9] FATAL ExceptionHandling.Models.EmailService+d__0.MoveNext - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

I'm trying to understand why do I get the above errors after the first attempt?

Comment: One line of code?? What are we supposed to understand here?

Comment: Why do you start a task inside a `Task.Run` then immedatly `.Wait()` on it, you are wasting CPU resources by doing that. Just call the function directly. Also by looking at your call stack I bet you have a `async void` or you are calling a `.Result` or a `.Wait()` on the task returned from `SendMailAsync` which is possibly part of your problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you give me an example of how that would look like?  The only examples I found online were like the ones I used.

Comment: @Bagzli, here's a simple explanation of what you *should* be doing with async page methods in ASP.NET: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is probably (at least partly) due to you disposing your `Client`.

Disposing an object instantiated *outside* of the scope of the `using` statement is a pretty unconventional use of the keyword, and it's easy to get it wrong.

A simple fix would be to create a new client instance every time:

```
using (MailClient client = CreateMailClient())
{
    await client.SendMailAsync(email.Message);
    return true;
}

private SmtpClient CreateMailClient()
{
    MailClient client = new MailClient();

    // Configure client.

    return client;
}
```

Comment: I see your point, I will need to restructure some of my logic then.

Comment: @Bagzli, I've suggested one way of going about it in my latest edit.