# Have multiple threads share method workload

Tags: c#

I have a method called `asyncStartList`, which sends a list of emails provided it, and I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple threads to speed up the process in cases where there are a lot of emails:

```
public async Task asyncStartList()
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();   

    for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    {
        currentMailAddress = emailingList[i];
        await Task.Run(() => MailingFunction());
        currentMailAddress = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Your mail to {0} was successfully sent!", emailingList[i]);
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", 
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    Console.WriteLine("Time for completion " + elapsedTime);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `MailingFunction()` is a simple SmtpClient and mail message.

Comment: OK, let us know how you go.  Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Your solution actually not run parallel, because of you wait for every each send operation. You can use paralel foreach/for keyword. Otherwise, you have to wait after all send operation executed.

```
public async Task asyncStartList()
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    // option 1
    Task[] tasks = emailingList.Select(s => Task.Run(() => { SendEmail(s); }).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    // option 1 end

    // option 2
    Parallel.ForEach(emailingList, email =>
    {
        SendEmail(email);
    });
    // option 2 end

    // option 3
    Parallel.For(0, emailingList.Length, i =>
    {
        SendEmail(emailingList[i]);
    });
    // option 3 end

    stopWatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    Console.WriteLine("Time for completion " + elapsedTime);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void SendEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    // Do send operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Parallel.ForEach` from the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. So instead for `for int i = 0;...` use `Parallel.ForEach(emailingList, address => {...})`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop for an example

Comment: This is the way to go.  I have used Parallel before to enable data parallelism.  The execution is scheduled on multiple threads based on your system environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your solution's performance is [CPU-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean), that is when you want to use parallel threads. If your solution is bound by something else-- e.g. the ability of the email server to handle requests-- what you actually should use is `async`, which is much simpler and much safer.

There are many ways to use async in this scenario, but here is a short and simple pattern that would work:

```
await Task.WhenAll
(
    emailingList.Select( async address => MailingFunctionAsync(address) )
);
```

Yes, that is all there is to it. This assumes that your email client not only has a `MailingFunction()` method but also a `MailingFunctionAsync()` method (e.g. using Outlook's [`SendAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) method or something similar).

Here is a sample `MailingFunctionAsync()` stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803264/send-mail-with-smtp-sendasync):

```
public async Task MailingFunctionAsync(string toEmailAddress)
{
    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
    message.Subject = SOME_SUBJECT;
    message.Body = SOME_BODY;
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common answer here is to use `Parallel.ForEach` (well apart from John Wu's answer that you should really consider). While on-the-outset `Parallel.ForEach` seems like an easy and good idea, its actually not the most optimal approach.

Here is the problem:

`Parallel.ForEach` uses the thread pool. Moreover, *IO bound* operations will block those threads waiting for a device to respond and tie up resources.

- If you have *CPU bound* code, *Parallelism* is appropriate;
- Though if you have *IO bound* code, *Asynchrony* is appropriate.

In this case, sending mail is clearly *I/O*, so the ideal consuming code would be asynchronous.

Furthermore, to use asynchronous and parallel features of the *.NET* properly, you should also understand the concept of *I/O threads*.

- Not everything in a program consumes CPU time. When a thread tries to read data from a file on disk or sends a TCP/IP packet through network, the only thing it does is delegate the actual work to a device; disk or network adapter; and wait for results.
- It’s very expensive to spend a threads time on waiting. Even through threads sleep and don’t consume *CPU* time while waiting for the results, it doesn’t really pay off because it’s a waste of system resources.
- To be simplistic, every thread holds memory for stack variables, local storage and so on. Also, the more threads you have, the more time it takes to switch among them.

*Though, the nice thing about `Parallel.ForEach` is its easy to implement, you can also set up options like Max Degree of Parallelism.*

So what can you do...

You are best to use `async`/`await` pattern and/or some type of limit on concurrent tasks, another neat solution is to [`ActionBlock<TInput>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [TPL dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.

**Dataflow example**

```
var block = new ActionBlock<MySomething>(
    mySomething => MyMethodAsync(mySomething),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

foreach (var something in ListOfSomethings)
{
    block.Post(something );
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

This approach gives you *Asynchrony*, it also gives you `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it doesn't waste resources, and lets *IO* be *IO* without chewing up unnecessary resources

***Disclaimer**, DataFlow may not be where you want to be, however I just thought I'd give you some more information on the different
approaches on offer*.